# Returning single records per month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a use case function that needs to returns a single row only for every end of month.

I tried using select distinct and it is showing multiple records for the same end of month

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
        WHEN eff_interest_balance < 0.01 THEN trial_balance_date
        WHEN date_paid < trial_balance_date THEN date_paid
    END as A
    , period 
FROM dbo.Intpayments[enter image description here][1]
WHERE loan_number = 60023
ORDER BY period ASC
```

Each row should return single date for each month

Comment: . . Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct is returning unique rows, not grouping them.  You are looking to aggregate rows.  This means using some combination of aggregate functions and group by.

What your current query is missing is some sort of logic for aggregating the rows that are in the same period.  Do you want to compare the sum of these values?  The min, the max?

In any case, the basic idea of aggregating and grouping would look like this - I don't think this summing is what you want, but the query shows the basic idea of aggregating and grouping:

```
SELECT
    period
    , SUM(eff_interest_balance) AS SumOfBalance
FROM dbo.Intpayments
WHERE loan_number = 60023
GROUP BY period
```

Comment: Hi Snow, thank you I was thinking of using Max too because it needs to get the last payment date for the month

Comment: The important thing is that you need to consider that you are (potentially) operating on multiple rows.  So, everything you select needs to either be part of the grouping (listed in the group by) or aggregated in some way (sum, avg, min, max, etc....)

Comment: Here is the updated query... SELECT DISTINCT  

 period, case when max (eff_interest_balance) < 0.01 THEN max (trial_balance_date)

when max (date_paid) < max (trial_balance_date) THEN max (date_paid) END as A

from dbo.Intpayments where loan_number =60023

group by period

Comment: Now the column is returning all nulls when it is suppose to be a date

Comment: again, you don't need distinct.  Though, this probably isn't the issue with your results.  You really need to provide some sample data in your original question.

Comment: Also, there seems to be a hole in your case logic - you specify two cases, but there is no default case for when the data doesn't meet the first two - this is likely the source of your nulls

Comment: Thanks Snow, I got the query to work now by taking out distinct and using GROUP. Next problem is I could not add that query to a view I created.